# Kubuntu 14.04 suddenly boots to black screen

Tags: boot, kubuntu

I ve had a dualboot of Kubuntu 14.04 and W8.1 for quite a while now (no fresh install). Recently after using W8.1 for few hours the Kubuntu goes from GRUB to **black screen** only (no cursor, no sounds). I managed to get to the tty1 by using the nomodeset option and attempting `startx` results in "no screens found" error.

The thing is I was not installing/updating anything. The only unusual thing I did was connecting an ipad mini for few seconds until I found out it does not charge from 5V ;-)

I am a relative newbie and I can't figure out much more. Any help would be appreciated!

Dell XPS L322X 2013, Intel HD graphics 4000

Answer (score 0):

So I have tried to: reinstall kubuntu-desktop, intel drivers, reconfigure xorg and few other things. Nothing helped and lead to the exact same symptoms as described above.

I backed up all my files from live USB and when I was decided to erase Kubuntu partition and clean install one again from Windows, I gave a desperate "last try" to booting into Kubuntu. The same way the issue with black screen came, it was suddenly gone. Everything works like charm now...